# Javascript - Readonly on beginning text input

Tags: javascript, input

I have this input with some text (it could be `personne` or `contacts`) :

[image]

Is it possible to block modification of the first word?

If there is `personne` or `contacts` in the input text, prevent the deletion of these from the input field but only allow entry after these words.

Comment: why not adding pseudo-element before the input?

Comment: You could check with a `.startsWith` at each keydown or keyup that the value of the input is not less than 'personne' and otherwise put it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's simple JS solution, you can write in it but can not delete:

```js
document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('keyup', val, false);
function val() {
  if (this.value.includes("personne ") === false) {
    this.value = "personne ";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="personne " size="30" id="myInput">
```

And you can even make sure if user types something, and selects the `personne`  with mouse and delete it with keyboard, to append it back again with value typed after it:

```js
document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('keyup', val, false);
function val() {
  if (this.value.includes("personne ") === false) {
    this.value = "personne " + this.value.substr(this.value.indexOf(' ') + 1);
    this.value = this.value.replace("personne personne", "personne ");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="personne " size="30" id="myInput">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```css
input{
padding-left:70px;
}
.input-container{
position: relative;
}
.input-container:after{
content: 'prersonne';
position:absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 5px;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```